# Logic: How to prove this argument is not valid

Tags: logic

Good day to all,

I need calcification on how to show this argument is not valid by finding a counterexample, but without using a truth table. Since there are 5 propositions I would need a 32 row truth table. It would be too time consuming to construct.

```
                    p
                    p v q 
                    p --> (r --> s)
                    t --> r

                   ∴ ~s --> ~t
```

Keeping it short I have this in the end.

> p is True
>
> q is False
>
> r is True
>
> s if False
>
> t is True

If so, how is that a counterexample? Shouldn't the argument be valid?

Thanks

This is how I worked it out:

My understanding is that for the first four premises we can`t deduce it inference rule as their value could be either true or false which the result will still give me true.

Hence we focus on the conclusion that ~t is "False" which makes ~s "False"
so that the conclusion will be true. **Such that we also narrow the input of t--> r . to be True and True. Since negation of t is False.**  So on and so forth until we reach the first premise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made a serious mistake in your produced counterexample. With $r$ being true and $s$ being false, then $r\rightarrow s$ is false, and with $p$ being true $p\rightarrow(r\rightarrow s)$ is false.

To be complete in investigating with truth table we first simplify and check which rows that are ruled out by the premisses. First of all we can eliminate $q$ as it is not used in the conclusion (in addition it doesn't rule out any possibility that the $p$ premise doesn't already rule out).

Of course every row with $P$ being false is ruled out by the first premise. This leaves us with a truth table with only $8$ rows. In addition $p\rightarrow (r\rightarrow s)$ rules out the rows where $s$ is false and $r$ is true (and $p$ is also true, but we already ruled out any row that $p$ is not) and the $t\rightarrow r$ rules out the rows where $r$ is false yet $t$ is true. This leaves us with:

$\begin{matrix}
r & s & t \\
\hline \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \text{ruled out by } t\rightarrow r \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & \text{ruled out by } t\rightarrow r \\
1 & 0 & 0 & \text{ruled out by } p\rightarrow(r\rightarrow s) \\
1 & 0 & 1 & \text{ruled out by } p\rightarrow(r\rightarrow s) \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}$

So we see that what is left is only rows with $s, t$ being both false, both true or $s$ being true and $t$ being false. Which all making $\neg s\rightarrow \neg t$ being true.

Comment: Oh , shoot.. Didn`t see my mistake . 

Yeah my  S suppose to be true .. since ~s  = False..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The argument is valid.

For the four premises to be all true, we must evaluate (1) $p$ as true, (2) $q$ as either true or false (we *cannot* infer which), (3) $r$ as false *or* $s$ as true (since $r\to s$ is an inference from evaluating $p$ being true), and (4) $t$ as false *or* $r$ as true.

In short, we must *resolve* to have $s$ as false *or* $t$ as false.   Therefore $\neg s\to \neg t$ will be evaluated as true when the premises all are so.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to say that by (1) and (3) we get $r\to s$ and by (4) $t\to r$, and combining these we now have $t\to s$ which is the contrapositive of the conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

One way to check if the argument is valid is to use a tree proof generator. [This tree proof generator](https://www.umsu.de/trees/) shows the argument is valid. If it found a branch that did not close with an "x", it would output a counterexample constructed from a branch that did not close.

[image]

To try finding a counterexample manually, consider the conclusion $\neg s \to \neg t$. What truth values of $s$ and $t$ would make that conditional false? If we set $s$ false, then $\neg s$ is true. If we set $t$ true, then $\neg t$ is false. If true implies false the conditional is false.

The conclusions provides constraints for valuations we assign to the other propositions.  Those valuations have to make all of the premises true.

---

Tree Proof Generator. https://www.umsu.de/trees/